# How do I enable the browser spell checker in WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I want to use the in-browser spell checker within the Drupal 7 WYSIWYG editor, which is currently disabled by default.

I found [this post](http://murfitt.net/blog/getting-browser-spell-checker-work-ckeditor-drupal) but the settings aren't availble in my Drupal module. When I go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring there doesn't seem to be a place to enable or turn off the disabled browser spell checker. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you using the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module or the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module?

Comment: @ShawnConn CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

The Check Spelling plugin is only included with CKEditor Standard and Full by default.

For the CKEditor module spell checking is enabled via the profiles.

Go to Configuration > Content authoring > CKEditor and edit each profile you to to it display on. Then under Editor Appearance drag the appropriate buttons to the "Current toolbar"

If you are using the WYSIWYG module it is also enabled through the profiles.

Go to Configuration > Content authoring > Wysiwyg profiles and edit each profile you want it to display on and check the "Check Spelling" option.

With CKEditor 4 you must enable "Spell check as you type" since the buttons have been merged into one with WYSIWYG.

Comment: Per my question I don't see "CKEditor" under Configuration > Content authoring. Does "The Check Spelling plugin is only included with CKEditor Standard and Full by default" mean that I would have to install the CKEditor "Standard" or "Full" module (this one? https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) to get the spellchecking functionality? Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 parts to the Editor: 1) The Drupal module (WYSIWYG or CKEditor) and 2) the CKEditor code.  First install the module and enable it (whichever one) then download and install the code per the instructions in the module. The Standard and Full versions are version of the Code from the CKEditor website.